# using pool.map() for on a single column of a DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, apply

I'm trying to parallelize the application of a function on a pandas data-frame.
The easy way to do it is:

```
pandarallel.initialize(progress_bar=True, verbose=0, use_memory_fs=True, nb_workers=2)
df.parallel_apply(lambda x: my_func(x['column1']), axis=1)
```

Yet, for some reason, the *pandarallel* library seems not to be working in my case.
Thus, I'm thinking of manually doing this with pool.map():

```
def parallelize_dataframe(df, func, n_cores=2):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, n_cores)
    pool = Pool(n_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df

df = parallelize_dataframe(df, my_func, n_cores=2)
```

However, I don't know how to change `pool.map()` to be applied only to 'column1' to obtain the equivalent code in line 2.

P.S. my_func is a function supposed to get images from a URL and apply an image-processing prediction on them.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting `df['column']` instead of `df`:

```
def parallelize_dataframe(df, func, n_cores=2):
    df_split = np.array_split(df['column'], n_cores)
    #                     added ^^^^^^^^^^
    pool = Pool(n_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df
```

Comment: I had tried this. Returns the following error:

Comment: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid